# Global variables in Handlebars if blocks

Tags: handlebars.js

Is it possibly to use global variables in Handlebars conditionals? I'm writing an app that lists a lot of objects, and I want users to be able to control which details are listed. For example, displaying only first names in a list of people, like so:

```
<ul>
{{#each people}}
    <li>
        <p>{{firstName}}</p>
        {{#if displayLastnames}}
        <p>{{lastName}}</p>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

I don't want to actually modify the data (for example, by removing the lastName attribute and doing `{{#if lastName}}`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also register a global helper named 'displayLastnames' and use it in a if :

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('displayLastnames', function(block) {
    return displayLastnames; //just return global variable value
  });
```

and just use it as in your sample :

```
  {{#if displayLastnames}}
    <p>{{lastName}}</p>
  {{/if}}
```

Comment: even not works for 1.0.0, `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'depth0.global_var')`, this fiddle only works for 1.0.0.beta6!

Answer (score 11):

Handlebars namespaces the variables so you can't directly access global variables. Probably the easiest thing to do is to add your own helper, something simple like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_displayLastnames', function(block) {
    if(displayLastnames)
        return block.fn(this);
    else
        return block.inverse(this);
});
```

and then in your template:

```
{{#if_displayLastnames}}
<p>{{lastName}}</p>
{{/if_displayLastnames}}
```

You'd probably want to put your "global" variables in their own namespace of course.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Y34b4/

Comment: What does block.inverse do?

Comment: @Don'tKnow See the "Conditionals" section of the "Block Helpers" docs: https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals