# Handlebars.js - Global Contexts

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Say I have a static list of users cached somewhere in my application like `App.Users`. I'll probably have the need to list my users in several dozen places in my application. Conventionally, I'll just need to pass my list in with my context to the template.

```
var tmpl = Handlebars.templates['TemplateName'];

var html = tmpl({
    model: model,
    users: App.Users
});
```

But this approach requires some wiring in both the template and the javascript. What I would like to do is specify this in the template alone so I don't need to remember this in my scripts. Consider something like this...

```
{{#each {{users}}}}
    <li> ... </li>
{{/each}}
```

...Where `users` is a helper function that just returns my `App.Users`. Wouldn't that be nice?

So that totally doesn't compile. What is another solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in Handlebars if blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790507/global-variables-in-handlebars-if-blocks)

Comment: Let me know if that's not what you had in mind, but it seems like the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Went with an abstract helper function deal... which let's be honest, seems to be the solution to 99% of Handlebars questions.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('global', function(context, options) {
    return options.fn(App.[context].toJSON()); // Object is Backbone Collection
})
```

And used in an example...

```
{{#global "Users"}}
    {{#each this}}
         <th>{{Name}}</th>
    {{/each}}
{{/global}}
```