# Handlebars JS: Pass variable to script from Handlebars.compile()

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

If I call my Handlebars JS script as follows,

```
var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#script').html());
$('#output').append(template(json));
```

Is it possible for me to pass a flag/variable/argument to `Handlebars.compile` which would I would be able to check inside the script?

```
var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#scriptQuestionsForActivity').html(), myFlag);
```

Script

```
{{#if (eq myFlag true) ... }}
```

I can't use a Helper function because there is no global variable or context I could check to get the value of `myFlag`. It's really an argument that either gets provided or not provided to the rendering process. I can't do this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkMyFlag', function() {       
    return myFlag; // This won't work, myFlag isn't stored as a global var
                   // Handlebars.compile is called either with or without it
                   // There shouldn't be a need to track this globally
});
```

Or am I overthinking this and there's an easy solution?

Comment: Could you please give the reason for conditional compilation? and What you are trying to achieve? I think you don't need to do this.

Comment: Why not adding your flag to your json data before passing it to your template ?

Comment: This question appears similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/11790507/3397771