# Passing variables to the default layout in handlebars express

Tags: javascript, web-development-server, express-handlebars

This is my code:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  helpers: {
      login: true,
    }
}));
```

It sets up the default layout of my page. In addition grabbing the default html I would like to have it grab a variable that I can set to `true` or `false`, then use that variable to conditionally display or not display a p.

```
{{login}}
{{#if login}}
    <p>logged In</p>
{{/if}}
```

in the `html` or `.handlebars` file I have the above code. when I run it, it displays true where the login variable is but the paragraph doesn't show up, even though login is set to true.

If I replace login with true it displays the paragraph...

The only thing I can think of is maybe the server is passing true as a string not a boolean.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790507/global-variables-in-handlebars-if-blocks